# Installing Elementary OS

Tags: system-installation

I'm installing Elementary OS on  my laptop, I' used a USB with de iOS (I made it with RUFUS on Windows), however it is taking a lot of time. It began last night and it doesn't finish, it takes about 8 h.

It appears this on the screen:

[image]

I don't know if that is normal, I previus installed Oracle Linux, and the last last time it had Ubuntu Budgie and It didn't take too much time.

I appreciate any help.

Ty

Comment: I would stop the installation, verify the integrity of your downloaded ISO, and (if it checks out) then try writing the ISO with a different program - like Balena Etcher.

Comment: Yep, it was the ISO, thank u very much!

Comment: I thought it probably was. I'll write up a quick answer in a minute, that way it's there for the next person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, the download was corrupted. Errors can happen during the download process and the larger the file is the more chances it has to be corrupted. This can happen during the download itself or as the file is being written to the drive.

To resolve this, you need to verify your download. The directions to do so are located on the [Elementary OS Installation](https://elementary.io/pl/docs/installation#choose-operating-system) page. This will vary depending on your operating system - and the checksum will change as the distro changes. So, be sure to check there and ensure your downloaded ISO is in fact bit-for-bit correct.

If you want to have your download automatically verified, you can actually use a [Torrent client](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_BitTorrent_clients) to download the ISO. You do this by clicking on the [magnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_URI_scheme) link in the download window.

For visual reference, this is what it currently looks like:

[image: use magnet download to automatically verify the file's correctness]

Files downloaded with a torrent client (using the magnet link) will automatically verify the integrity. The added bonus is that you can keep your torrent client open and help the project by saving the download site(s) some bandwidth.